# Can you wrap each command in GNU's make?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I want to inject a transparent wrap command on each shell command in a make file.  Something like the `time` shell command. (However, *not* the `time` command.  This is a completely different command.)

Is there a way to specify some sort of wrapper or [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for each shell command that [GNU Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Derivatives) will issue?

Comment: Sure, apply the wrapper in each command. I really don't think you can wrap all commands with one gesture.

Comment: You might be able to substitute your own shell which could do the wrapping (per-line).  Per-command is trickier because the lines are parsed by the shell, not by make.

Comment: Ah, that's the way to do it, jdigital.  Bash provides a way to re-escape the command -- `"$@"`.  I just need to do something like  `my_cmd "$@" `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of. You can tell make to use a different shell.

```
SHELL = myshell
```

where `myshell` is a wrapper like

```
#!/bin/sh
time /bin/sh "$0" "$@"
```

However, the usual way to do that is to prefix a variable to all command calls. While I can't see any show-stopper for the `SHELL` approach, the prefix approach has the advantage that it's more flexible (you can specify different prefixes for different commands, and override prefix values on the command line), and could be visibly faster.

```
# Set Q=@ to not display command names
TIME = time
foo:
    $(Q)$(TIME) foo_compiler
```

And here's a complete, working example of a shell wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULTZ=/home/rbroger1/repos/knl/results
if [  "$1" == "-c" ] ; then
    shift
fi

strace -f -o `mktemp $RESULTZ/result_XXXXXXX` -e trace=open,stat64,execve,exit_group,chdir /bin/sh -c "$@"  | awk '{if (match("Process PID=\d+ runs in (64|32) bit",$0) == 0) {print $0}}'

# EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done things like modify the PATH env variable in the Makefile so a directory with my script linked to all name the bins I wanted wrapped was executed rather than the actual bin.  The script would then look at how it was called and exec the actual bin with the wrapped command.

ie. `exec time "$0" "$@"`

These days I usually just update the targets in the Makefile itself.  Keeping all your modifications to one file is usually better IMO than managing a directory of links.

*I defer to [Gilles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998363/can-you-wrapper-each-command-in-gnus-make/5998728#5998728). It's a better answer than mine.*

Answer (score 0):

The program that GNU `make(1)` uses to run commands is specified by the `SHELL` make variable. It will run each command as

```
$SHELL -c <command>
```

You cannot get make to not put the `-c` in, since that is required for most shells. `-c` is passed as the first argument (`$1`) and `<command>` is passed as a single argument string as the second argument (`$2`).

You can write your own shell wrapper that prepends the command that you want, taking into account the `-c`:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval time "$2"
```

That will cause `time` to be run in front of each command. You need `eval` since `$2` will often not be a single command and can contain all sorts of shell metacharacters that need to be expanded or processed.